# How to install latest virt-manager in Debian?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm using Debian stable and in debian stable virt-manager version is 1.4.0, but I need to use version 1.5.1 because 1.4.0 has one bug.

I went to https://virt-manager.org/download/ and downloaded source, then I go to virt installation folder and used

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

But I got error

```
running install
Using sysprefix=/usr
running build
Generating /home/user/Downloads/virt/virt-manager-1.5.1/build/virt-manager
Generating /home/user/Downloads/virt/virt-manager-1.5.1/build/virt-install
Generating /home/user/Downloads/virt/virt-manager-1.5.1/build/virt-clone
Generating /home/user/Downloads/virt/virt-manager-1.5.1/build/virt-convert
Generating /home/user/Downloads/virt/virt-manager-1.5.1/build/virt-xml
Generating man/virt-manager.1
Generating man/virt-xml.1
Generating man/virt-install.1
Generating man/virt-clone.1
Generating man/virt-convert.1
running build_i18n
Writing po/POTFILES.in
intltool-update -p -g virt-manager
unable to execute 'intltool-update': No such file or directory
Removing po/POTFILES.in
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'po/POTFILES.in'
```

That are install instructions

````
# Basic Install

For starters, if you just want to run `virt-manager/virt-install` to test out
changes, it can be done from the source directory:
```sh
./virt-manager
```

To install the software into `/usr/local` (usually), you can do:
```sh
python setup.py install
```

To build an RPM, you can run:
```sh
python setup.py rpm
```

`setup.py` generally has all the build and install commands, for more info see:

   - `python setup.py --help-commands`
   - `python setup.py install --help`
   - [Python Standard Build and Install](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#standard-build-and-install)


## Pre-requisite software

A detailed dependency list can be found in
[virt-manager.spec.in](virt-manager.spec.in) file.

Minimum version requirements of major components:

   - python >= 2.7
   - gtk3 >= 3.14
   - libvirt-python >= 0.6.0
   - pygobject3 >= 3.14
   - libosinfo >= 0.2.10

On Debian or Ubuntu based distributions, you need to install the
`gobject-introspection` bindings for some dependencies like `libvirt-glib`
and `libosinfo`. Look for package names that start with `'gir'`, for example
`gir1.2-libosinfo-1.0`.
````

Comment: Did you I stall the dependencies as advised in the debian / ubuntu section?

Comment: How to install...might be off-topic per our FAQ. How to solve the particular error you are showing us to be able to proceed is not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the inttool package.

For that do :

```
sudo apt get install  intltool
```

From https://packages.debian.org/stretch/intltool

> Package: intltool
>
> Utility scripts for internationalizing XML
>
> Automatically extracts translatable strings from oaf, glade, bonobo
>   ui, nautilus theme and other XML files into the po files.
>
> Automatically merges translations from po files back into .oaf files
>   (encoding to be 7-bit clean). The merging mechanism can also be
>   extended to support other types of XML files.

PS. took out the automake recommendation. It comes as a dependency.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package inttool
Also I cant find it here https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=inttool

Comment: @J.Boe Edited the text for answering it.

Comment: @GAD3R Fault was mine, the original answer was written in a mobile, and the spelling checker probably kicked in.